# count columns having specific value for a row

Tags: r

I want to count the columns having a specific value/limit.

Example:
A dataframe has columns a0, a1, a2, ... a9

I want now to count the A-Columns having a value more than 1.0 and store this value in another column (e.g. s0) of the data frame.

This should be done for every row in the data frame.

Thx in advance

Comment: what have you done so far, do you have some code written or some working examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(a0=sample(0:5,20,replace=TRUE),a1=sample(0:5,20,replace=TRUE))

df$s0 <- apply(df,1,function(x) sum(x>1))
```

or

```
df$s0 <- rowSums(df>1)   ## Suggested by Sotos
```

Comment: Have a look at `?rowSums`

Comment: This worked for me. thx for support. df$s0 <- apply(df[,4:13],1, function(x) sum(x>1) )

Comment: Accept answer if found usefull